# Html table from a php array

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have this array, can someone help me put it into a html table? teable heads should be Name, Category, Startdate, Created.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [remoteid] => 4
            [cat_id] => 1
            [cat_name] => Miscellaneous
            [cat_description] => 
            [sortorder] => 10001
            [fullname] => Test3
            [shortname] => tst23
            [idnumber] => 
            [summary] => 
            [startdate] => 1426629600
            [created] => 1426609147
            [modified] => 1426609147
            [self_enrolment] => 0
            [enroled] => 0
            [in_enrol_date] => 1
            [guest] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [remoteid] => 3
            [cat_id] => 1
            [cat_name] => Miscellaneous
            [cat_description] => 
            [sortorder] => 10002
            [fullname] => Test2
            [shortname] => tst2
            [idnumber] => 
            [summary] => 
            [startdate] => 1426629600
            [created] => 1426609034
            [modified] => 1426609034
            [self_enrolment] => 0
            [enroled] => 0
            [in_enrol_date] => 1
            [guest] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [remoteid] => 2
            [cat_id] => 1
            [cat_name] => Miscellaneous
            [cat_description] => 
            [sortorder] => 10003
            [fullname] => Test
            [shortname] => tst
            [idnumber] => 
            [summary] => 
            [startdate] => 1426629600
            [created] => 1426602753
            [modified] => 1426602753
            [self_enrolment] => 0
            [enroled] => 0
            [in_enrol_date] => 1
            [guest] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: Just start with some code! We will then fix it and show where the errors are

Comment: the problem is i dont know how to do that, i need it for a school project

Comment: research php `foreach` loops.

Comment: Then you may want to start with learning the PHP basics

Comment: @BalasoiuAndrei Stackoverflow is not for completing your projects for you. If you have done your research properly, and are stuck then you can ask your question.

Comment: I started to research php foreach loops, i will come back with questions if needed xD. Thank you guys:)

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php 
     $array = Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [remoteid] => 4
                    [cat_id] => 1
                    [cat_name] => Miscellaneous
                    [cat_description] => 
                    [sortorder] => 10001
                    [fullname] => Test3
                    [shortname] => tst23
                    [idnumber] => 
                    [summary] => 
                    [startdate] => 1426629600
                    [created] => 1426609147
                    [modified] => 1426609147
                    [self_enrolment] => 0
                    [enroled] => 0
                    [in_enrol_date] => 1
                    [guest] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [remoteid] => 3
                    [cat_id] => 1
                    [cat_name] => Miscellaneous
                    [cat_description] => 
                    [sortorder] => 10002
                    [fullname] => Test2
                    [shortname] => tst2
                    [idnumber] => 
                    [summary] => 
                    [startdate] => 1426629600
                    [created] => 1426609034
                    [modified] => 1426609034
                    [self_enrolment] => 0
                    [enroled] => 0
                    [in_enrol_date] => 1
                    [guest] => 0
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [remoteid] => 2
                    [cat_id] => 1
                    [cat_name] => Miscellaneous
                    [cat_description] => 
                    [sortorder] => 10003
                    [fullname] => Test
                    [shortname] => tst
                    [idnumber] => 
                    [summary] => 
                    [startdate] => 1426629600
                    [created] => 1426602753
                    [modified] => 1426602753
                    [self_enrolment] => 0
                    [enroled] => 0
                    [in_enrol_date] => 1
                    [guest] => 0
                )

        )
 print "<table>";
foreach($array as $row){
     print " <tr> \n";
      foreach ($row as $name=>$value){
  print "<td>$value</td>\n";        
     } // end field loop
print "</tr>  \n";
 } // end record loop
  print "</table> \n";
    ?>
```

Comment: @BalasoiuAndrei how did you get to this array it doesn't sound right, it looks like its a output of an array

Answer (score 0):

Try the following for this array:

```
echo "<table>";
$i = 0;
foreach($array as $row){
    echo " <tr>";
    if ($i == 0)
        foreach ($row as $name=>$value)
            echo "<th>$name</th>";
    foreach ($row as $name=>$value)
        echo "<td>$value</td>";
    echo "</tr>"; 
    $i++;
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way using simple `foreach` loop but change your array as you need. I have added a demo array.

```
$array=array(
             array('fullname'=>'Test2','category'=>'test1','startdate'=>1426629600,'created'=>1426609034),
             array('fullname'=>'Test3','category'=>'test3','startdate'=>14266234300,'created'=>2323232)
            );
?>
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="name">Name</th>
        <th class="category">Category</th>
        <th class="startdate">Start Date</th>
        <th class="created">Created</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach($array as $key=>$values){
    ?>
    <tr>

        <td><?php echo $values['fullname']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $values['category']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $values['startdate']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $values['created']; ?></td>

   </tr>
    <?php }?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```